# Creating a list of tuples of different lists

Tags: python, zip

Let's assume that I have the following three lists (l1, l2, l3). How can I create a new list where each element is a tuple of elements of the lists (l_desired)? It actually works as an extended version of the zip method in python.

In simpler words, given `l1, l2, l3`, how can I create `l_desired`?

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l3 = ['Jess', 'Muss']

l_desiered = [(1, 'a', 'Jess'), (1, 'b', 'Jess'), (1, 'c', 'Jess'), 
              (1, 'a', 'Muss'), (1, 'b', 'Muss'), (1, 'c', 'Muss'), 
              (2, 'a', 'Jess'), (2, 'b', 'Jess'), (2, 'c', 'Jess'), ...]
```

`

Comment: Are you talking about the cartesian product? What is the expected size? If so, `[(x,y,z) for x in l1 for y in l2 for z in l3]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have already said, use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l3 = ['Jess', 'Muss']
>>> list(itertools.product(l1, l2, l3))
[(1, 'a', 'Jess'), (1, 'a', 'Muss'), (1, 'b', 'Jess'), (1, 'b', 'Muss'), (1, 'c', 'Jess'), (1, 'c', 'Muss'), (2, 'a', 'Jess'), (2, 'a', 'Muss'), (2, 'b', 'Jess'), (2, 'b', 'Muss'), (2, 'c', 'Jess'), (2, 'c', 'Muss'), (3, 'a', 'Jess'), (3, 'a', 'Muss'), (3, 'b', 'Jess'), (3, 'b', 'Muss'), (3, 'c', 'Jess'), (3, 'c', 'Muss')]
```

To achieve the sort order specified in your question, you can sort the results like this:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(itertools.product(l1, l2, l3), key=itemgetter(0,2,1))
[(1, 'a', 'Jess'), (1, 'b', 'Jess'), (1, 'c', 'Jess'), (1, 'a', 'Muss'), (1, 'b', 'Muss'), (1, 'c', 'Muss'), (2, 'a', 'Jess'), (2, 'b', 'Jess'), (2, 'c', 'Jess'), (2, 'a', 'Muss'), (2, 'b', 'Muss'), (2, 'c', 'Muss'), (3, 'a', 'Jess'), (3, 'b', 'Jess'), (3, 'c', 'Jess'), (3, 'a', 'Muss'), (3, 'b', 'Muss'), (3, 'c', 'Muss')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.product` to get the Cartesian product (every possible combination of values) from a group of lists

```
import itertools
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l3 = ['Jess', 'Muss']
for element in itertools.product(l1, l2, l3):
    print(element)
```

Or you can use list comprehension

```
[element for element in itertools.product(l1, l2, l3)]
```

Or try this,

```
list(itertools.product(l1, l2, l3))
```

Comment: why `[4,5]`? otherwise great answer

Answer (score 1):

This will produce output identical to `l_desired` if that is important to you, otherwise the `itertools.product` solutions are tidier.

Example:

```
from pprint import pprint

l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l3 = ['Jess', 'Muss']

l_desired = [
    (l1_elem, l2_elem, l3_elem)
    for l1_elem in l1
    for l3_elem in l3
    for l2_elem in l2
]

pprint(l_desired)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'a', 'Jess'),
 (1, 'b', 'Jess'),
 (1, 'c', 'Jess'),
 (1, 'a', 'Muss'),
 (1, 'b', 'Muss'),
 (1, 'c', 'Muss'),
 (2, 'a', 'Jess'),
 (2, 'b', 'Jess'),
 (2, 'c', 'Jess'),
 (2, 'a', 'Muss'),
 (2, 'b', 'Muss'),
 (2, 'c', 'Muss'),
 (3, 'a', 'Jess'),
 (3, 'b', 'Jess'),
 (3, 'c', 'Jess'),
 (3, 'a', 'Muss'),
 (3, 'b', 'Muss'),
 (3, 'c', 'Muss')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order does not matter you can use itertools:

```
from itertools import product


l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l3 = ['Jess', 'Muss']
l_desired = list(product(l1,l2,l3))
```

output:

```
[(1, 'a', 'Jess'), (1, 'a', 'Muss'), (1, 'b', 'Jess'), (1, 'b', 'Muss'), (1, 'c', 'Jess'), (1, 'c', 'Muss'), (2, 'a', 'Jess'), (2, 'a', 'Muss'), (2, 'b', 'Jess'), (2, 'b', 'Muss'), (2, 'c', 'Jess'), (2, 'c', 'Muss'), (3, 'a', 'Jess'), (3, 'a', 'Muss'), (3, 'b', 'Jess'), (3, 'b', 'Muss'), (3, 'c', 'Jess'), (3, 'c', 'Muss')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply do this without importing `itertools` just by `list comprehension`:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l3 = ['Jess', 'Muss']
```

Finally:

```
l_desiered=list(((x,y,z) for x in l1 for y in l2 for z in l3))
```

Now If you print `l_desired` you will get your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Nested for loops:

```py
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l3 = ['Jess', 'Muss']
out = []
for l in l1:
    for l_2 in l2:
        for l_3 in l3:
            out.append((l, l_2, l_3))
print(out)
'''
[
(1, 'a', 'Jess'), (1, 'a', 'Muss'), (1, 'b', 'Jess'),
(1, 'b', 'Muss'), (1, 'c', 'Jess'), (1, 'c', 'Muss'), 
(2, 'a', 'Jess'), (2, 'a', 'Muss'), (2, 'b', 'Jess'), 
(2, 'b', 'Muss'), (2, 'c', 'Jess'), (2, 'c', 'Muss'), 
(3, 'a', 'Jess'), (3, 'a', 'Muss'), (3, 'b', 'Jess'), 
(3, 'b', 'Muss'), (3, 'c', 'Jess'), (3, 'c', 'Muss')
]'''
```